# Python module import error without using sys module

Tags: python, import, module

I am trying to use my own custom module, but It is unable to load the module.

This is a hierarchy structure of my custom module.

```
sources\
    set1\
        module_1
        module_2
    set2\
        module_3
        set3\
            module_4
```

I imported these modules like below

```
from sources.set1.module_1 import *
from sources.set2.module_2 import method
...
```

And it occurs import error.
The error message is `No module named 'sources`

I use VScode, and Python 3.7 (I expect that I don't need to use **init**.py)

I've googled this problem and I've found 2 solutions. However, these weren't helpful.

1. Using `sys.path.append()`

   This couldn't be a solution for me. Because I am working with teammates, and it is not allowed to add this code just for me
2. Adding PYTHONPATH environment variable

   I've already added PYTHONPATH with `"C://directories//sources"`,but it doesn't soleve import error. However, I found that this solution allows below codes instead of the original codes.

```
import module_1  #This occurs no error, But I can't use it
...
```

Comment: What happens if you call your script from the command like? (This is to establish whether it's a Python issue, or a VCode issue.)

Comment: @brunns Same error occurs when I run it in command

Answer (score 0):

You have to call as a packages, for that you have to use  **init**,py in each subdirectory https://www.learnpython.org/en/Modules_and_Packages

Comment: I added it. and there is no red underline in my code, but my python can't still load my module. It still occurs `No module name sources`